# Flag Permutations problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Hi I'm trying to understand Permutations and Combinations in depth and I have this question:

> How many ways are there to place $25$ different flags on $10$ numbered (diff) flagpoles if the order of the flags on a flagpole is
>  
>   (a) not relevant?
>   (b) relevant?
>   (c) relevant and every flagpole flies at least one flag?

For a), the answer is $10^{25}$. However, I don't get it. I assume its $10!$ but I don't really know... I want to understand this as much as I can. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: What does it mean to place a flagpole on another flagpole? Maybe it should be to place one of the 25 flags on a flagpole, maybe... not clear what the set-up is.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it's 25 different flags

Answer (score 2):

**Just a start:**

For part (a): Each flag can go on any of the 10 poles. That is 10 choices for each of the 25 flags to be placed, so number of ways 10*10*...*10 with 25 copies of 10 being multiplied, i.e. $10^{25}.$

This is an application of the multiplication principle. To make that more see-able suppose at a restaurant they offer 3 entrees and 2 desserts. Then in all you have 3*2=6 ways to choose your meal. In general if an overall task T can be described as a sequence T1,T2,...,Tn of smaller tasks, then the number of ways to do T is obtained on multiplying each of #(T1),#(T2),...,#(Tn), where by #(Tk) is meant the number of ways to do task Tk.\

Parts (b),(c) will be more complicated--- I'll leave that to another answerer for now or maybe you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

(b): First decide how many flags to go on each flagpole.  That can be done using 'stars and bars'.
Then arrange the flags, from the first flag of the first flagpole to the last flag on the tenth flagpole.  That can be done in 25! ways.

Comment: Is 'stars and bars' a method?

Comment: It is a method for counting [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition).

Answer (score 1):

> How many ways are there to place $25$ different flags on $10$ numbered flagpoles if the order of the flags on a flagpole is not relevant?

We have a choice of ten flagpoles for each of the $25$ flags, so there are $10^{25}$ ways to distribute the flags to the flagpoles.

> How many ways are there to place $25$ different flags on $10$ numbered flagpoles if the order of the flags on a flagpole is relevant?

The number of ways of distributing $25$ identical flags to ten different flagpoles is equal to the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + x_{10} = 25 \tag{1}$$
in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the insertion of nine addition signs in a row of twenty-five ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 0$, $x_4 = 4$, $x_5 = 3$, $x_6 = 5$, $x_7 = 3$, $x_8 = 4$, $x_9 = 1$, and $x_{10} = 0$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 1 in the non-negative integers is 
$$\binom{25 + 9}{9} = \binom{34}{9}$$
since we must choose which nine of the thirty-four symbols (twenty-five ones and nine addition signs) will be addition signs.  Since the order in which the flags are placed on the flagpoles is relevant, we multiply this result by the $25!$ orders in which the flags can be arranged.  Hence, the number of ways to place $25$ different flags on $10$ numbered flagpoles if the order of the flags on a flagpole is relevant is 
$$\binom{34}{9} \cdot 25!$$

> How many ways are there to place $25$ different flags on $10$ numbered flagpoles if the order of the flags on a flagpole is relevant and each flagpole flies at least one flag?

The number of ways of distributing $25$ identical flags to ten different flagpoles if each flagpole flies at least one flag is the number of solutions of equation 1 in the positive integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of nine addition signs in the $24$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $25$ ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 4$, $x_5 = 2$, $x_6 = 3$, $x_7 = 2$, $x_8 = 4$, $x_9 = 3$, and $x_{10} = 1$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 1 in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{24}{9}$$
Since the order of the flags on a flagpole is relevant, we multiply this result by $25!$ to obtain
$$\binom{24}{9} \cdot 25!$$
ways of placing $25$ different flags on $10$ numbered flagpoles if the order of the flags is relevant and each flagpole flies at least one flag.